# Ubuntu 16.04 Intel network wifi issue

Tags: 16.04, wireless, intel-wireless

A fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, no errors, using WIFI but after I go the website speedtest.net or download large files the Wifi disconnects completely.

Also, looked up the issue and followed this tutorial: https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005480/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html

and still no luck.

Network card: Intel 82579V Gigabit

Ubuntu version: 16.04

IfConfig:

```
ifconfig
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:9c:dc:27:d0:6f  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb200000-fb220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:57366 (57.3 KB)  TX bytes:57366 (57.3 KB)

wlxd0df9a2d5ee0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:df:9a:2d:5e:e0  
          inet addr:192.168.0.6  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d3ec:3703:c98a:c93d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4814 errors:0 dropped:1005 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2680296 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:1005823 (1.0 MB)
```

Initially, the connection is fine but upon downloading large updates or files it disconnects and have to restart in order connect back to wifi.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; iwconfig`. You likely do not have an Intel wifi device as they haven't made a USB model in years, the Intel device you found is ethernet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct driver downloads helped me with this issue. After getting the right driver's, installed them and did a apt-get update/upgrade rebooted the system and was good to go no issues.

Here is the web site for intel driver's.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005520/graphics-drivers.html